# How can the attribute change when other attribute click in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks

I'm a beginner in prestashop. I'm going to change other attributes when attribute click.

For example, there is car products in my shop and there are three attributes "2m", "3m", "4m" by width about the car.

The price of the car is 500USD. "2m" attribute raises the price of the car product to 2+USD. "3m" attribute raises the price of the car product to    3+USD. "4m" attribute raises the price of the car product to 4+USD.

Now, If I click the "3m" attribute, the total price of the car will be    503USD and the price of "2m" and "3m" attributes is not changed. I would like to change the price of another attribute. for example, when I click the "3m" attribute, the price of "2m" and "3m" attribute should be changed to "-1" and "+1".

Finally, I would like to change the price of other attributes expect what I click the attribute. Can I accomplish these projects on the Prestashop admin page? I can't find the clue there. So I started to write PHP or tpl code in my FTP server. I don't know that I have to write in the controller or tpl file. I'm going to write code in tpl file. So is to right to implement that?

Below the code.

```
{foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute    item=group_attribute}


       <li class="input-container" title="{$group_attribute.name} - {$group.name}">
            <input class="input-radio attri" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"       name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}" {if       $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}/>

            <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
            {if isset($ahpvarsaver) && $ahpvarsaver && $group_attribute.price > 0}

              {if $product.discount_type === 'percentage'}
                 {$ta=$product.discount_percentage/100}
                 {$tas=str_replace("-","",$ta)}
                 {$tass=str_replace("%","",$tas)}

                <span style="text-align:center;display:none" class="iprice {$ta} {$tas} {$tass}" con="{$group_attribute.price}">      <center>



                {$foo=$group_attribute.price-$group_attribute.price*$tass}    
                {$num=number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '')}
                {l s='+%1$s' sprintf=[Tools::displayPrice($num)]}

               </center>
               </span>

              {else}

                <span style="text-align:center;" class="iprice " con="{$group_attribute.price}"><center>
                  {l s='+%1$s' sprintf=[Tools::displayPrice($group_attribute.price)]}
                </center></span>

              {/if}
            {/if}
            <span class="st-input-loading"><i class="fto-spin5 animate-spin"></i></span>
          </li>
       {/foreach}

       {*/foreach*}
   Please answer my question in more detail. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "Combinations" function of prestashop

1. Create new / edit product
2. On the right side you see **Combinations** select ** Product with combinations **
3. Click on the **Combinations** tab
4. Create a combination for 2m, 3m and 4m
5. You can change the price for each combination

Hope this helps you!